# Segmentation Fault While Returning Struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

Okay so for an assignment I have to create a Queue ADT, but my code is failing at the very start.

The very first method call for every test is que_create, which is what is seg-faulting. Here is the method:

```
QueueADT que_create(int (*cmp)(const void *a, const void *b)) {
    QueueADT queue = {0, 0, 1, 10, 0, calloc(10, sizeof(void *)), cmp};
    return queue;
}
```

The struct:

```
typedef que_adt {
    unsigned int head;
    unsigned int rear;
    unsigned int empty;
    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int nitems;
    void **array;
    int (*cmp)(const void *a, const void *b);
} QueueADT;
```

The method seg-faults on the line containing
    return queue;

GDB:
Break points on the queue initialization and the return line.
Before

```
queue = {head = 0, rear = 0, empty = 0, capacity = 0, nitems = 0, array = 0xff0000000000000000, cmp = 0x1}
```

After

```
queue = {head = 0, rear = 0, empty = 1, capacity = 10, nitems = 0, array = 0x603010, cmp = 0x7ffffffffe938}
```

Valgrind:
One error: Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x400796 at que_create (queueADT.c:34) // <- line for the return of the method

I've tried looking up answers to this as I'm very confused, but all of the questions regarding this sort of thing are not as simple as mine. I'm literally initializing a struct and returning it. I tried commenting out the calloc in the initialization and also the cmp function, but the same error persisted. Any suggestions?

Comment: @paulsm4, note that the compiler will copy the structure. He does not return (a pointer to) a local variable, which would be wrong. Upon return, the value of the structure must be compied to a structure of the receiver using assignment, which the compiler will do.

Comment: Please post a minimal complete example, including the definition of `QueueADT`.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `QueueADT`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I added the definition of the struct.

Comment: Is the function cmp defined somewhere?  I see the declaration. But where is the definition?  Isn't the definition of cmp() should be taken out of typedef?  It looks like cmp() is taking 2 parameters of this type.

Comment: @Nguial Yes. The function cmp is a function pointer to a function that is supplied by the testing file. Right now it's just a memory address to a function, but later I use it while inserting into the queue, but that's not relevant because the program doesn't even get hat far.

Comment: @DevinK  What is this project supposed to do?  Is it sorting QueueADT data?

Comment: @Nguaial It's a Queue ADT, with FIFO when the compare function is NULL and an ascending sorting Queue but-not-really-a-queue when the cmp function is not NULL. I just want to know why it's seg-faulting on the first method though when creating the queue... :/

Comment: Please post a **minimal and complete example**. Why is this so hard to understand? A complete program which we can compile and see for ourselves how it segfaults.

Comment: @DevinK I just ran your code and it returned fine.  BTW, you are missing struct in typedef definition.  But that should cause compilation error.

Comment: @AlexP I'm not able to access what is being passed in. It's through a grading system where I don't have access to the actual tests. I'm simply writing the implementation so I don't have an example to provide.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct que_adt {
     unsigned int head;
     unsigned int rear;
     unsigned int empty;
     unsigned int capacity;
     unsigned int nitems;
     void **array;
     int (*cmp)(const void *a, const void *b);
 } QueueADT;

 int
 compare( const void *a, const void *b)
 {
    return 1;
 }

 QueueADT que_create(int (*cmp)(const void *a, const void *b)) {
     QueueADT queue = {0, 0, 1, 10, 0, calloc(10, sizeof(void *)), cmp};
     return queue;
 }

 int
 main(void)
 {
      QueueADT q = que_create( compare );

      return 0;
 }
```

Within the gdb, I typed 'p q' and I got

```
 (gdb) p q
 $1 = {head = 0, rear = 0, empty = 1, capacity = 10, nitems = 0, array = 0x602010, cmp = 0x40052d <compare>}
```

There isn't much difference between your code and this one. I copied and pasted it.  The only difference is that I had to define a dummy compare() function.